# Jquery Fullcalendar when I change events source all properties are lost

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar

I'm trying to do some filters with arShow Jquery Fullcalendar and ajax web script.
I create the fullcalendar this way (simplyfied):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     firstDay: 1,
     selectable: true,
     events: 'somewebscript.php'
});
```

But when I want to change events source from jquery event handler the "firstDay" and "selectable" parameters are lost. I use this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
    events: 'somewebscript.php?showholidays=true' 
});
```

Why? I only want to redraw the events array with same properties.

Comment: I had same problem, try to have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940182/change-fullcalendar-event-source-after-load

Answer (score 0):

I think that by calling `.fullCalendar` again you're re-initializing the calendar.

You should look at the [fullcalendar docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/), I believe you can reset the source and 'refresh' events using one of the methods instead of reinitializing the calendar.

Comment: OK, first I have removed the events with .fullcalendar('removeEvents' ); and then I have added the new source with .fullcalendar( 'addEventSource', source);

Comment: My problem now is when user press next month button. The filters are lost, any idea how to pass same parameters next/prev month?

Comment: have a look at what I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/jordanbaucke/qMBrX/3/ I did a couple of _addEventSource_ and _removeEventSource_ calls